# Is it possible to introduce 4-velocity very early on?

Tags: special-relativity, velocity, vectors, education

I was wondering if it would be possible to teach new physics students about 4-velocity straight away at the beginning of their studies. Keeping the regular notion of the three dimensional velocity $\vec{v}$, but right away explaining that there is more to it, a 'fourth dimension', as described by Einstein's theory...

I'm not entirely certain how to raise this question and indeed if this is the best place to do this... I'm sure there has to have been literature written on this, but it's very challenging to find (I personally can't find anything suitable).

Obviously general/special relativity needs to 'degenerate' into classical mechanics when $c$ is huge compared to the velocity scale of a classical problem - I was wondering how to signal this to prospective physics learners; that this tacit assumption indeed results in considering a whole different space of outcomes, a completely different (simplified?) analysis.

I'm partially asking this because I found relativity etc. the most challenging part of my physics studies. Suddenly one is told that our reality is wholly different than what we have known so far.

As an engineer, I've not chosen to get very involved in this, though I believe that these concepts can be taught earlier on, to 'get used to' this 'unusual' reality which usually eludes us. To me, it was a brief sidenote during the course of my study, yet one which made me wonder and wonder! I've not had the time to study it properly, and it's unlikely that I will in the nearest years, but perhaps recognizing that this 'jump' from classical mechanics to relativity isn't as easy as taking one "ten credit course".

I believe this could be a valuable lesson, which could in turn help many a prospective theoretical physicist... Now - please excuse this question if it's been raised before - personally I couldn't find a post which would express the sentiment which I'm trying to express now. I have done a fair bit of research on my part in seeking these answers and they've not been clear enough for me - this is why I'm ultimately posting this message here.

Comment: Special relativity doesn't "degenerate" into classical mechanics, at any velocity. Please don't teach it that way. Also, please don't teach that time is the fourth dimension. Time is a completely different phenomenon from space, even in relativity and your students need to keep an open mind about that. Einstein didn't talk about it that way, if I recall correctly, Minkowski came up with the _mathematical_ concept, which ignores the physics of time, completely. In general, please make sure you know what you are talking about _before_ you teach.

Answer (score 1):

1) Usually special relativity is taught at the end of the semester, after the class got through rotations, which they, on average, don't understand; torques, which are pseudo vectors and for this reason blow their minds up... By the time they get to relativity they are done! If you teach the same kind of course, it is unavoidable, that they will get confused.

2) Early introduction of time-space has to be backed up by understanding of symmetries of space and basic group theory concepts. The problem with relativity is not that it is introduced late, but that standard math courses are too weak for it to be taught and understood correctly.